# Singly Linked List suppose to print (12, 7) but instead prints (127, )

Tags: java, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I am trying to write a program that takes an integer and inserts it into the second position in the linked list, but when I run my program it prints out (127, ) when I want it to print out (12, 7). I know it is probably an easy fix, but I am unsure of how to fix this small error. I have tried switching words around like head and tail and next, but nothing I do seems to work. Any input would help a ton!

```
public class IntSinglyLinkedList {

  private static class Node {

    private Integer element;            

    private Node next;       

    public Node(Integer e, Node n) {
      element = e;
      next = n;
    }

  private Node head = null;              

  private Node tail = null;              
  
  private int size = 0;   
                  
  public IntSinglyLinkedList() { }    

  public int size() { return size; }


    public void addSecond(Integer e) {
    if(head == null)
      return;
    Node Final = new Node(e, head);
    Final.next = head.next;
    head.next = Final;
  }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      IntSinglyLinkedList sl = new IntSinglyLinkedList();
      sl.addFirst(12);
      sl.addSecond(7);
      System.out.println(sl.toString());
    }
}
```

My toString also looks like this if this is any help!

```
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("(");
    Node walk = head;
    while (walk != null) {
      sb.append(walk.getElement());
      if (walk != tail)
        sb.append(", ");
      walk = walk.getNext();
    }
    sb.append(")");
    return sb.toString();
  }
```

my addFirst method

```
public void addFirst(Integer e) {                
    head = new Node(e, head);              
    if (size == 0)
      tail = head;                           
    size++;
  }
```

Comment: Where does the nested Node class actually end? Your toString() method uses getNext() but that's not present in the code you posted. It may be necessary to get the full code to diagnose this error. Similarly you didn't send the getFirst code. Also it might be a good idea to combine the addFirst and addSecond methods into one using the size field of your list to determine whether or not it's the first usage, since that would increase clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Why aren't you just using a LinkedList?

```
LinkedList<Integer> ll = new LinkedList<>();
ll.add(12);
ll.add(1, 7);
System.out.println("LinkedList is: " + ll.toString());
```

Output would be: LinkedList is: [12, 7]

Answer (score 0):

You never update your tail element after your `addFirst`, so the `,` will not be printed after the first element.

You have to add `tail = Final;` in your addSecond method to make *this particular example* to print correctly.

That answers the specific question of why you get `(127,)` printed instead of `(12, 7)` in this particular case.

However, it is hard to see where you are going with this. Are you planning to write a new method for every element you want to add? It would make more sense to have a general `add`:

```
public Node add(final Integer i) {
  final var node = new Node(i, null);
  if (size == 0) {
    head = node;
  } else {
    tail.next = node;
  }
  tail = node;
  size++;
  return node;
}
```

Comment: I just added the addFirst method.

Comment: Ok, that changes things. I rewrote the answer to adjust for this new information.

Comment: `You have to add tail = Final;` - It'll not solve the issue with the reference to the `tail`